# Global.asax notification when an unhandled error occurs?

Tags: notifications, global-asax

on my production server sometimes we get server error due to some time out issues.

I would like to receive a notification to my Phone or email as soon as my server is down.

How can i do that?
I guess i have to write a  function on global.asax

```
 Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
End Sub
```

my server is on Windows 2008 R2

.Net Framework 3.5 
VB.Net

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Correct, just replace `'Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs` with whatever code you want to handle the error (send email, log to db etc.)

Comment: yes, i was looking for some help on the Business logic in that function. I am not good with VB Code and start up would be a great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage existing logging modules to handle this for you. For example, you can simply add [Error Logging Modules and Handlers for ASP.NET](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to your solution and not change a single line of code. You configure *elmah* in your web.config and it can send you emails automatically when unhandled exceptions occur.

The web based error page from *elmah* is also very nice during development.